# begin try catch on sql server 2005, how to send the ERROR_stuff to the calling parent?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, error-handling, transactions

you have this procedure

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test1
    AS
    BEGIN
        begin transaction
        begin try
          exec dbo.test2
          commit transaction
        end try
        begin catch
            SELECT
                ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
                ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
                ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
                ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
                ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
                ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
           rollback transaction
        end catch
    END
```

and this one

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test2
    AS
    BEGIN
        begin transaction
        begin try

          commit transaction
        end try
        begin catch
           rollback transaction
            if @@trancount = 0
            begin
                SELECT
                    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
                    ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
                    ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
                    ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
                    ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
                    ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
             end
             else
                --return the select above to the parent while raising an error
        end catch
    END
```

how to do re-throw the error to the calling parent?

I know I could do this;

```
  raiserror(ERROR_MESSAGE(),ERROR_SEVERITY(),ERROR_STATE())
```

but how to get **ERROR_LINE()**, **ERROR_PROCEDURE()** and **ERROR_NUMBER()**?

I need to be able to just do the same select in every catch, if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [raiserror](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)  in your child sproc.

Comment: you could put those values directly into your custom error message, or you could populate a custom errors table with this info and read from it in the parent.

Comment: for what I can see, rethrowing error should be implemented in 2008 or next version, for 2005, the only solution is raiserror.

Answer (score 0):

We use a stored proc (was udf, but added exception logging) that we call in every catch block to concatenate what we need and RAISERROR again.

The calling stored proc calls the error handler proc again and add more info etc.

The ERROR_xxx() functions are available in the error handler proc because it's in the catch block scope.

Eventually, the client (c# in our case) gets the exception.